# Examples of functions $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z:\;$ surective, injective, bijective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm having a problem finding functions $f:Z \rightarrow Z$, such that:

- $f$ is onto but not one-to-one,
- $f$ is one-to-one but not onto,
- $f$ is neither one-to-one or onto,
- $f$ is both one-to-one and onto (bijective).

Please help me
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for you to sort out:

$$\begin{align}&f(n)=2n-1\\{}\\&f(n)=\begin{cases}f(1)=1\\f(n)=n-1&,\;\;n\neq 1\end{cases}\\{}\\&f(n)=1\;,\;\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb Z\end{align}$$

The above three examples cover all **but one** of the cases you mention.  Find out which one and realize that it is trivial and come up with an example for it.

Comment: In your second function, did  you mean to add the qualifier "$n=2$?

Comment: so the 1st function is neither onto nor 1-1, the 2nd is 1-1 but not onto, but i was lost with the 3rd

Comment: @RoryDaulton No, but thanks for pointing that out as I realized the typo I had there.